# Elemento mudar de uma lista para outra em divs diferentes usando html e javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, script

Olá,
Estou tentando fazer os itens de uma lista passar para outra ao serem clicados.
Se eu clicar em algum elemento da lista 1 ele deve ir para lista 2. Se depois for clicado algum elemento da lista 2 ele deve ir para lista 1 (mesmo que ja tenha vindo de lá).
A primeira parte estou conseguindo fazer (ir da 1 para 2) porém não estou conseguindo fazer que retorne caso clico no item adicionado à lista 2.

```js
$(function() {
                   $( ".AA" ).click(function(){ 
                   $(".Lista2").append(this);
                   this.classList.remove('AA');//muda a classe do elemento de AA para BB
                     this.classList.add('BB');
                      });
                   });

                   $(function() {
                   $( ".BB" ).click(function(){ 
                   $(".Lista1").append(this);
                   this.classList.remove('BB');//Muda classe do elemento de BB para AA
                     this.classList.add('AA');
                      });
                   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Lista1">
            <h3></i>Itens1</h3>
            <ul>
              <li class="AA">Item 1</li>
              <li class="AA">Item 2</li>
              <li class="AA">Item 3</li>
              <li class="AA">Item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="Lista2">
          <h3>Itens2</h3>
          <ul>      
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes de dar uma ideia genérica de como resolver, e que possa ser útil a outras pessoas, é preciso comentar alguns problemas no seu código:

- `$(".Lista2").append(this);` - aqui está movento o item `<li>`, que deve estar dentro de uma tag `<ul>` para dentro de um elemento `<div>` (quem tem a class "Lista2"). Deveria mover o elemento para dentro da outra `<li>`
- `this.classList.remove('AA')` e `this.classList.add('BB')` - isso não vai funcionar direito, porque o seu seletor para atribuir o evento "click" aos elementos é justamente a classe (`$( ".AA" ).click...`). Note que, quando esse comando é executado, a todos os elementos com a classe "AA", assim como os elementos com a classe "BB" é atribuida uma função, que é a que vai "mover" o elemento. No inicio, não há elementos com a classe "BB", logo, nenhum evento é atribuito! Quando mudou de classe, nada vai acontecer ao elemento após ele receber a classe "BB". Quando há mudanças no **DOM** (*Document Object Model*), os eventos não são "reatribuídos". Logo, sempre que mudar algumas características/atributos ou criar um novo elemento, é necessário atribuir a função novamente, por isso, aqui seria melhor atribuir o evento "click" ao elemento, por exemplo com o seletor `$("li").click...`, porque independete da lista que estiver, o `<li>` não vai mudar.
- `$(function() {` - tem dois blocos desse, isso não é necessário, poderia associar os eventos "click" um em seguida do outro no mesmo bloco, essa função não precisa existir duas vezes.

Dito isso, uma ideia, como comentei na segunda observação, seria fazer um seletor direto no elemento `<li>`, não seria necessário a classe, bastaria ter algum atributo no elemento "pai" para saber em qual `<ul>` ele se encontra e mover para a outra. Para isso podemos por uma classe ou ID na lista.
Para saber qual a lista, basta fazer `$(this).parent()`, onde `parent` é o elemento imediatamente "acima" no **DOM**, ou seja, a `<ul>`, que é onde cada `<li>` deve estar inserido. Com isso, basta por exemplo ver qual o ID para saber em qual lista está e mover para a outra, assim por exemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  // seletor pela lista, que é o que vai ser movido com "click"
  $("li").click(function() {
     // verifica o ID da lista onde o  elemente está
     var idUlPai = $(this).parent().attr("id");

     // de acordo com a lista, move a outra
     // a seguir move para a outra lista, ou seja append de UL para UL
     if (idUlPai == "ul1") {
        $("#ul2").append(this);
     } else {
        $("#ul1").append(this);
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>Itens1</h3>
  <ul id="ul1">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>Itens2</h3>
  <ul id="ul2">      
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Entendi o que estava fazendo errado! Estou me aventurando agora nessa linguagem. Você ajudou bastante!